# [SQL]Removing day in yyyy/mm/dd datetime format in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I'm using PostgreSQL, but this question is for any modern dbms
I want to basically convert a datetime column which has yyyy/mm/dd into just yyyy/mm

I tried getting months and year separately and using Concat, but the problem is the month comes as a single digit integers for values < 10 and that messes up ordering

```
select *,
concat(date_part('year' , date_old), '/', date_part('month' , date_old)) as date_new
from table
```

| date _old | date_new |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-01-20 | 2010-1 |
| 2010-01-22 | 2010-1 |
| 2010-11-22 | 2010-11 |

Comment: Which dbms are you using? concat and date_part are both product specific functions.

Comment: I would think any solution for this is going to be rdbms specific.

Comment: use a CASE statement to prefix month numbers less than 10 with a 0

Comment: As a side note: a `date` column does not have any format. If you see it displayed as `yyyy/mm/dd` then this formatting is applied by the SQL tool you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_char()`

```
to_char(date_old, 'yyyy/mm')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **display** your date in the format `YYYY-MM` then

- In PostgreSQL ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=713790a7e3bb922e54760dfe3e0cf6d3)) and Oracle ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=23cfd921cd193e6fc3ff754f4da9c719)), use `TO_CHAR`:

  ```sql
  SELECT TO_CHAR(date_old, 'YYYY/MM') FROM table_name;
  ```
- In MySQL ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ee72411fd59b008c5e84dbfa31b98b9)), use `DATE_FORMAT`:

  ```sql
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_old, '%Y/%m') FROM table_name;
  ```
- In SQL Server ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=151cdfa0297654e47132ffebaecbb60e)), use `CONVERT` or, if you are using SQL Server 12 or later, `FORMAT`:

  ```sql
  SELECT CONVERT(varchar(7), date_old, 111) FROM table_name;
  SELECT FORMAT(date_old,'yyyy/MM') FROM table_name;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

## Don't do this.

If you're able to use the `date_part()` function, what you have is *not actually formatted as the `yyyy/mm/dd` value you say it is.* Instead, it's a **binary** value that's not human-readable, and what you see is a convenience shown you by your tooling.

**You should leave this binary value in place!**

If you convert to `yyyy/mm`, *you will lose the ability to directly call functions like `date_part()`*, and *you will lose the ability to index the column properly*.

What you'll have left is a `varchar` column that only pretends to be a date value. Schemas that do this are considered **BROKEN**.